# ReCaptcha with ZF3 wrong value

Tags: zend-framework, recaptcha, zend-framework3

I use the newest Zend Framework available, and now i want to use ReCaptcha on my form. Together with some other elements, the ReCaptcha element is defined by:

```
$pubKey = 'replaced by the actual pubkey';
$privKey = 'replaced by the actual privkey';
$recaptcha = new \Zend\Captcha\ReCaptcha(['pubKey' => $pubKey, 'privKey' => $privKey]);

$this->add(array(
    'attributes' => array (
        'data-role' => 'none',
    ),
    'name' => 'captcha',
    'type' => 'captcha',
    'options' => array(
        'captcha' => $recaptcha,
    ),
));
```

This code validates the form in the controller:

```
public function contactAction () {
    $contactForm = new ContactForm();
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $contactForm->setData($this->getRequest()->getPost());

        if($contactForm->isValid()){
            // send actual mail
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('page', ['lang' => $this->translator->getLocale(), 'page' => 'contact']);
        }
    }
    $viewModel = new ViewModel ([
        'contactForm' => $contactForm
    ]);
    $viewModel->setTemplate('application/index/contact');
    return $viewModel;
}
```

And finally, this is the view:

```
<?= $this->form($contactForm); ?>
```

To me, this code is pretty straightforward and should work. However, on sending the contact form, it displays the error 'Captcha value is wrong'. Any ideas?

Comment: if you step through the code execution, with xdebug, of the `Captcha->isValid()` method, where does it enter the error state and why?

Comment: I am not accustomed with xdebug :\

Comment: You should have a look ;-) Stepping through the code during the execution gives a great amount of insights.

Comment: I had (have) similar issue, and to be honest I cannot see where isValid() is called as the response is always the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to name the element according to the rules of Google. With this code, it works like a breeze

```
$pubKey = 'replaced by the actual pubkey';
$privKey = 'replaced by the actual privkey';
$recaptcha = new \Zend\Captcha\ReCaptcha(['pubKey' => $pubKey, 'privKey' => $privKey]);

$this->add(array(
    'name' => 'g-recaptcha-response',
    'type' => 'captcha',
    'options' => [
        'captcha' => $recaptcha,
    ]
));
```

Anyways, as always the ZF Docs are very short and lack examples.